# Notepad++ auto trim trailing spaces on save only for some file extensiones

Tags: notepad++

I'm using a Notepad++ macro to 'Trim trailing and save' files. And I have setup to [Ctrl]+[S] hotkey.

But, sometimes I'm editing files that I need to keep their spaces. Is it possible to set up a macro only for some file extensions? Or there is another way to auto apply Trim trailing spaces on save only for some file extensions?

Note: I use Notepad++ to edit php files but also MarkDown files that need blank spaces at the end of some lines.

**Update:** I'm using Notepad++ for Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Use the "Trim Trailing and save" macro:

```
Macro -> Trim Trailing and save
```

The default shortcut is:

```
Alt + Shift + s
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use python script to do that.

Write a script called during the startup.py script that register a call back on notification filesaved:

```
notepad.callback(saveFile, [NOTIFICATION.FILESAVED])
```

In the function `saveFile`, you check the extention. If the extension is valid, you can call trim trailing space function, then call save function.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ on windows.

This can be done on windows?
Where to put the script?

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío if you install & enable the Python Script plugin then under Plugins you will have a Python Scripts entry with its own configuration entry. User scripts are stored somewhere like: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\PythonScript\scripts